# Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver on Ionic

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm building app with ionic 
i have add firebase cloud message, everything work fine
But today, when i build that show error.

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. remove plugins
3. clear & clean cache
4. remove package-lock.js
5. npm i
   6  ionic cordova platform add android
   7  ionic cordova prepare
   8  ionic cordova build android

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   37 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 30 up-to-date
>   D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
/*/*/*/*/*/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found out it was because of the firebase and googleplus plugins. Finally found a solution that worked for me :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Simply adding these plugins removed any build error.

Comment: You're welcome :) In case someone has issues with firebase plugin still, you can use one the fixed forks like https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib or https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase instead. Think about `cordova clean android` to get a clean state before rebuilding as well.

Comment: In case someone stumbles here, the common fork now used by community developers on the firebase plugin is https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase