# Error running "ionic cordova build android' after installin firebase package.Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

After i installed the firebase package from ionic docs, and configured firebase for cloud-messaging, when i run "ionic cordova build android" i get these errors:

```
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:610: error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                        : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getByteArray(key, namespace);
                                                            ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:629: error: method getValue in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                        : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getValue(key, namespace);
                                                            ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:686: error: no suitable method found for setDefaults(Map<String,Object>,String)
                        FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaultsToMap(defaults), namespace);
                                                          ^
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(Map<String,Object>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:885: error: cannot find symbol
                        myTrace.incrementCounter(counterNamed);
                               ^
  symbol:   method incrementCounter(String)
  location: variable myTrace of type Trace
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                                                             ^
  required: Context
  found: FirebasePluginMessagingService,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
33 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 28 up-to-date
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:610: error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                        : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getByteArray(key, namespace);
                                                            ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:629: error: method getValue in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
                        : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getValue(key, namespace);
                                                            ^
  required: String
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:686: error: no suitable method found for setDefaults(Map<String,Object>,String)
                        FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaultsToMap(defaults), namespace);
                                                          ^
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(Map<String,Object>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:885: error: cannot find symbol
                        myTrace.incrementCounter(counterNamed);
                               ^
  symbol:   method incrementCounter(String)
  location: variable myTrace of type Trace
D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                                                             ^
  required: Context
  found: FirebasePluginMessagingService,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Projects\Evento\Evento\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried removing the plugin and reinstalling.

I have updated the cordova, ionic and firebase to the latest version.

Also, I have removed firebase and installed from ionic docs and removed onTokenRefresh and replaced with onTokenNew into the subclass FirebaseMessaingSerice, and safely deleted FirebasePluginServiceId.

I have removed the platform and reinstalled all plugins.

I have updated the `google-services.json` but no effect.

Still I get these errors and cannot run in android.

My guess is there is some version incompatibility here, but cannot find it.

Here are my versions and configuration:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1 (C:\Users\arbi_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Build.Gradle

```
/* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
*/

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } // Fabrics Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        google() // Google's Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Project Properties

```
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/evento-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.1
```

Comment: First question is where did you get the tutorial for integrating Firebase, maybe it's out of date as I notice this in the logs: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: I bought in udemy, but the integrations phase was watched from ionic docs and the installation of packages were taken directly from ionic docs

Comment: Have you tried installing AndroidX plugins? See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694042/1928380

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will try this out and tell if it works.Thanks.

Comment: It solved my problem.Thankss a lot.You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

So that other people can benefit, like I did*, Jeremy Belolo's answer here solved the problem both for the person that askes this question (according to his statement anyway :-) ) and for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694042/1928380

I copy the important part: Just adding these plugins, solved the problem.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

*
*This is not my answer, nor do I claim any credits for it. But, I was not opening this item for days, because in the search results it showed 0 answers, when in fact the answer hidden in the comments solves my problem too!*

[image: Entry showing 0 answers]